# Release schedule for ROS Noetic

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a release schedule/timeline/roadmap for releasing ROS Noetic?

When is it likely to available in Ubuntu (next Ubuntu release Focal Fossa is scheduled for April 2020)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340902/release-schedule-for-ros-noetic/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2020-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Release schedules (or more correctly: dates) are typically listed on the [wiki/Distributions](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions) page. Specifically in the [Upcoming Releases](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions#Upcoming_releases) section.

For Noetic, there is this:

> The next release of ROS 1 will be called ROS *Noetic Ninjemys*.

> See [ros-infrastructure/rep#202](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/202) for proposed updates to [Target Platforms (REP 3)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) with details on targetted versions of OS, C++, Python and other libraries and tools.

Both `wiki/Distributions` and `ros-infrastructure/rep#202` show the current planned released date for Noetic to be: May, 2020.

And it's not really a roadmap per se (more of a TODO list), but [ros/rosdistro#21513](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/issues/21513) (*Noetic Kick-off and Release Checklist*) has details on the status of the (many) tasks that have to be completed before May.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2